# MissingURLMapping: No URLMap entries found in application configuration

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm new in GAE development, I've just created a simple API but I'm unable to run my app, because I keep getting the error **No URLMap entries found in application configuration**.

Here's my *app.yaml* file

```
application: gw2
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: main.api_server

libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

And here is my *main.py* file where I've declared the **api_server** variable

```
from google.appengine.ext import endpoints

import api

api_server = endpoints.api_server([api.GW2Service])
```

*GW2Service* inherits from *remote.Service*

*Edit* I'm using command line tools (Ubuntu 12.04)

Where's the mistake?

Thanks in advance. *Eric ~H*

Answer (score 1):

1. You start server from the app or command line?
2. Try using "import endpoints" not from ... import endpoints
3. In app.yaml set endpoints version to latest.
4. Move GW2Service to main.py and test if server is ok. The problem might be generated by file name "api".